# How to use EmberJS ListView with data from remote source

Tags: listview, ember.js

EmberJS team released [ListView](http://emberjs.com/list-view/) couple of months ago and the whole idea sounds great. But the given example is just a very simple array with 10000 objects and nothing else.

Most of applications for an infinite scrolling list views must be able to load slices from a remote source, replacing the pagination way (as Facebook and Twitter do), but in that case I must be able to load the additional amount of items as the user scroll and not loading all at once to show in smaller portions (as the simple example does). I mean, this is nothing new and quite common.

So, question is: how to do it? EmberJS Router's model function doesn't receive anything like a page number and ListView also doesn't send it.

I did open an [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/list-view/issues/122) on it and the answers sound as there is something obvious I am not seeing.

So, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion on the ember codebase github, I thought you actually just wanted to use ListView.

ListView's promise is that it can load very large data sets without them all being in the VIEWPORT at once... that is, it behaves very much like iOS's Collection Views in terms of an optimized display mechanism. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Infinite Loadinging lists aren't a primary ListView use case, IMHO.

It sounds very much like you want the infinite scrolling list that discourse uses. (If you haven't seen it, go to http://discuss.emberjs.com and click on a long topic, and then scroll down and note how it loads).

This article will probably be helpful and at least spur your research:
http://eviltrout.com/2013/02/16/infinite-scrolling-that-works.html

Note that this requirement isn't particularly simple or easy and not really easy to answer in a few minutes on stack overflow. However, the discourse source code **is** open source, and that blog entry **is** by one of the main guys from discourse, so it should definitely point you in the right direction. :)

[ edit ] : By the way, this article (http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/03/infinite-scrolling-get-bottom/) should make it fairly clear that there's no "general 'correct' use case or implementation" around this kind of thing because it really depends what you're trying to achieve in your app. Ember doesn't make these decisions for you. The essential parts of what you're trying to achieve are to use pagination (which we can do with the new upcoming queryparams feature), and to use that to drive AJAX JSON API requests that populate your live-data-bound template. If you investigate both of those things, and take a good look into the way discourse handle it, then you'll understand how to do what you want to do.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know how to do it with raw JS or jQuery. I just want to make it following EmberJS patterns. I didn't know Discourse was based on EmberJS, I am goingt o study it. Thanks again!